# PHP remove a condition in a foreach

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to edit a WordPress plugin which sorts the streams from the platform.

I just want to show any stream from the ID.

This is the link to the page controller (bootstrap)

```
<?php
$streamHeading = get_option('pixiehuge-stream-heading', 'Our streams');
$streamsection = get_option('pixiehuge-stream-section-enable');

$streams = pixiehuge_streams();
global $sectionNum;
?>

<?php if($streamsection && !empty($streams)): ?>
    <section id="streams"<?php echo (!empty($sectionNum) && $sectionNum == 1) ? ' class="firstWithBg"' : '' ?>>
        <?php
        $sList = [
            'twitch' => pixiehuge_streams(false, 'twitch'),
            'youtube' => pixiehuge_streams(false, 'youtube'),
            'mixer' => pixiehuge_streams(false, 'mixer'),
        ];
        $active = false;
        ?>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="section-header">
                <article class="topbar">
                    <h3>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="7px" height="8px"><path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="rgb(57, 191, 253)" d="M-0.000,0.435 C-0.000,0.805 -0.000,7.292 -0.000,7.546 C-0.000,7.877 0.338,8.123 0.672,7.930 C0.940,7.775 6.293,4.649 6.750,4.381 C7.050,4.205 7.045,3.786 6.750,3.611 C6.421,3.415 1.048,0.272 0.658,0.054 C0.373,-0.106 -0.000,0.071 -0.000,0.435 Z"></path></svg>
                        <?php echo esc_attr($streamHeading); ?>
                    </h3>
                </article>
                <!-- /TOP-BAR -->

                <article class="bottombar">
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($sList as $id => $items): ?>
                            <?php if(!empty($items)):?>
                                <li<?php echo !$active ? ' class="active"' : '' ?>>
                                    <a href="#<?php echo esc_attr($id) ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo esc_attr($id) ?></a>
                                </li>
                                <?php
                                if(!$active) {
                                    $active = $id;
                                }
                            endif; // If not empty ?>
                        <?php endforeach; // Get categories ?>
                    </ul>
                </article>
                <!-- /BOTTOM-BAR -->
            </div>
            <!-- /SECTION-HEADER -->

            <div class="tab-content content">

                <?php foreach($sList as $id => $items): ?>
                <?php if(!empty($items)): $i = 1; ?>
                <div id="<?php echo esc_attr($id) ?>" class="list<?php echo ($active == $id) ? ' active' : '' ?>">
                    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>

                <?php if($i == 1): ?>
                    <div class="left">
                        <article class="streamBox large" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($item['thumbnail']) ?>');">
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_home_url(null, 'stream/' . $item['slug'])) ?>" class="playBtn">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="10px" height="12px"><path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" d="M10.000,6.000 C10.000,6.412 9.789,6.773 9.473,6.968 L9.474,6.968 L1.629,11.835 C1.626,11.837 1.623,11.839 1.620,11.841 L1.616,11.843 L1.616,11.843 C1.457,11.942 1.270,12.000 1.071,12.000 C0.480,12.000 -0.000,11.496 -0.000,10.875 L-0.000,10.875 L-0.000,1.124 L-0.000,1.124 C-0.000,0.503 0.480,-0.000 1.071,-0.000 C1.270,-0.000 1.457,0.057 1.616,0.156 L1.616,0.156 L1.620,0.159 C1.623,0.160 1.626,0.162 1.629,0.164 L9.474,5.031 L9.473,5.031 C9.789,5.227 10.000,5.587 10.000,6.000 Z"></path></svg>
                            </a>
                            <div class="details">
                                <span class="stream <?php echo esc_attr($id) ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($id) ?></span>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_home_url(null, 'stream/' . $item['slug'])) ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($item['title']) ?></a>
                                <h6><?php echo esc_attr($item['author']) ?></h6>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /LEFT -->
                <?php else: // Large thumbnail ?>
                <?php if($i == 2): ?>
                    <div class="right">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($i == 4): ?>
                        <div class="small">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <article class="streamBox" style="background-image: url('<?php echo esc_url($item['thumbnail']) ?>');">
                                <div class="details on-hover">
                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_home_url(null, 'stream/' . $item['slug'])) ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($item['title']) ?></a>

                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_home_url(null, 'stream/' . $item['slug'])) ?>" class="cta-btn">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="9px" height="8px"><path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" d="M4.688,0.182 C4.437,0.442 4.437,0.865 4.688,1.126 L6.805,3.326 L0.643,3.326 C0.288,3.326 -0.000,3.625 -0.000,3.993 C-0.000,4.362 0.288,4.661 0.643,4.661 L6.805,4.661 L4.688,6.861 C4.437,7.122 4.437,7.544 4.688,7.805 C4.939,8.066 5.346,8.066 5.597,7.805 L8.811,4.466 C8.928,4.345 9.000,4.178 9.000,3.993 C9.000,3.809 8.928,3.642 8.811,3.521 L5.597,0.182 C5.346,-0.079 4.939,-0.079 4.688,0.182 Z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                            <?php if($i == count($items) || $i == 3): ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>

                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                </div>
                <!-- /CONTENT -->
            </div>
            <!-- /CONTAINER -->
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't like PHP Object so I'm quite lost. I know I have to remove `$sList` Lines 12 > 16 since I don't want to sort it from Youtube...

But then I don't know how to edit the foreach line 51 `foreach($sList as $id => $items)` to do a foreach elements ID with no conditions anymore. Just a foreach of any elements in the TABLE.

I tried to do that from scratch:
*line 51*

```
<div class="tab-content content">

    <?php foreach($stream as $streams){ ?>
        <p><?php echo $stream['title']; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

But it didn't work... And I can't tell you the error

**EDIT**

This is working but I can't order it by ID DESC and limit it to 4 results...

```
            <div class="tab-content content">
                <?php foreach($streams as $key => $stream): ?>
                    <p><?php echo $stream['title']; ?></p>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please post code directly into your question; links to other sites may become invalid in the future.

Comment: There is 103 lines, it's more comfortable that way

Comment: As long as you’re comfortable with no response...

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure if I understood correctly what are you trying to do. Maybe is because you are running the loop the other way around? Try `foreach($streams as $stream)` instead of `foreach($stream as $streams)`.

Answer (score -1):

This is working "fine"

```
            <div class="tab-content content">
                <?php foreach($streams as $key => $stream): ?>
                    <p><?php echo $stream['title']; ?></p>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```